# nextjs navigate from dynamic route to static route

Tags: next.js, routes

I have a nextjs application, with a dynamic and static routes, when in the dynamic path and try to navigate to static path, i cant

this is my dynamic route

`notice/[slug]`

and the static route is `notice/`

for example if i'm in `notice/test` and try to navigate to notice i'm getting `notice/notice`

examples:
[dynamic route structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbgIv.png)

[link to navigate to dynamic routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32gHs.png)

[link to navigate to static routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCQRy.png)

Comment: How are you navigating?

Comment: using next link

Comment: Can you show the code you used ?

Comment: I already put the link to the code in the post

Comment: Does this answer question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174836/next-js-link-and-paths?